# Add JavaScript to a page without access to core files?

Tags: nodes, javascript, 7

I apologize in advance if this is a really simple question, but I'm pretty new to Drupal and still figuring out my way around things. So I was wondering if it is possible to add JS to a certain node or page of Drupal if I don't have access to the core library of files? I've searched around before and a lot of people have talked about somehow inserting a file into the directory, but I'm only granted access to the Drupal pages and the Appearance settings where I can add to/edit the CSS of a page.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If the developer has granted your user role access to the appropriate input formats and and has it configured to allow JS then yes, you can.

You may see a select box under one or more of the fields that allows you to select a filter such as "filtered HTML", "Full HTML" etc..

This is however normally locked down to prevent content editors from breaking a site, so I would be surprised if your limited role had access to unfiltered HTML/JS input.

A quick way to test if it works would be to add `<script>alert('test');</script>` in the box and save/refresh the page.